# Cannot echo and printf to tty port on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, echo, linux-device-driver, tty

I'm trying to send data to a usb device. I can do so perfectly on linux, but on mac, I try to do

```
echo "hi" > tty.usbserial-00000000
```

or

```
printf "hi" > tty.usbserial-00000000
```

It gets stuck in the process. I can't even control-c to exit out. However, "screen" works perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Finding same problem. Still not understand. Howver, if you end up here, pulling the USB cable at least free up the stuck process and let you try again.